# Choose layout depending on a string

Tags: android, android-layout

So, my fragment activity gets some string [from the array of names] from another fragment. And I have a lot of XML layouts with the names [from the same array]. 
For example, if activity gets string **"dogs"**, I want it to set/show **dogs.xml** layout.

It's clear that I can't do this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String LAYOUT_NAME = getArguments().getString("layout_name");
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.LAYOUT_NAME, container, false);
    return v;
}
```

Of course I can make it work with **Switch/Case**, but I'm sure it's possible to code it the way I imagine.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
int id= getResources().getIdentifier(LAYOUT_NAME, "layout", getPackageName());
```

(I wouldn't use a full uppercase name for a variable)

Answer (score 0):

Using `onCreateView()` indicates you refer to your fragment code, not activity's . The simplest approach would be to simply pass that string to the fragment using `setArguments()`. Then you can do `getArguments()` in your fragment, check the value and inflate proper layout as you want

**EDIT**

```
public Integer getLayoutIdByName( String name ) {
    Integer layoutId = null;

    try {
        Class res = R.layout.class;
        Field field = res.getField( name );
        layoutId = field.getInt(null);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // no such layout
    }

    return layoutId;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I wrote its fragment activity, and its not a problem to get that string. The problem is to use this string AS layout name e.g. if string = "dogs" - open dogs.xml

Comment: This can be done (see edited answer), but how many different strings you can have? 10? if so, make just plain `if/else` construct

Answer (score 0):

How to load a layout by name:

```
 setContentView(getResources().getIdentifier("name_of_layout", "layout", "yourpackagename"),);
```

Be careful though.  This might fail if you obsfucate your app.